# how do you do html encode using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html-encode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript/jQuery HTML Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding)

I have html tags need to be encoded.

```
<b>test</b>
```

I need to encode it to :

```
&lt;b&gt;test&lt;/b&gt;
```

I am using escape, but it doesn't work.

```
document.write(escape("<b>test</b>"));
```

the result I got is

```
%3Cb%3Etest%3C/b%3E
```

this is not what I expected. is there another way to do html encode using javascript?

Comment: this is NOT a duplicate. an answer is this: `str => { let elt = document.createElement('span'); elt.textContent = str; return elt.innerHTML;}`

Comment: document.write(('<b>test</b>').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;'));